# Change last octet in IP awk

Tags: shell, awk, sed

Assume having the following file

```
Somestring 1.2.3.4 more charachters and strings
Somestring 1.2.3.5 more charachters and strings
Somestring 1.2.3.6 more charachters and strings
```

I want to change the last octet in IP:

```
Somestring 1.2.3.x more charachters and strings
Somestring 1.2.3.x more charachters and strings
Somestring 1.2.3.x more charachters and strings
```

How can I achieve this in awk or sed?

What I did is:

```
awk '{match($0,/[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+/); ip = substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH-1); print ip }' file
```

but this only prints the ip and is not entirely correct.

Furthermore I tried:

```
awk '{split($2,ip,".") gsub(ip[2],"x"); print}'
```

but this is also not correct since It replacing first octet as well.

```
Somestring x.2.3.x more charachters and strings
Somestring x.2.3.x more charachters and strings
Somestring x.2.3.x more charachters and strings
```

Thanks for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `sed` for this:

```
$ sed -E 's/ (([0-9]{1,3}\.){3})[0-9]{1,3} / \1x /' file
Somestring 1.2.3.x more charachters and strings
Somestring 1.2.3.x more charachters and strings
Somestring 1.2.3.x more charachters and strings
```

This looks for a space followed by three sets of `[0-9]{1,3}\.` (a one to three digit number followed by a dot), which is captured into `\1`.  Then we also replace a last set of `[0-9]{1,3}` and a final space.  This is all replaced by `␣\1x␣` where `\1` is the first group of three numbers and dots.

Comment: Works nicely thanks! Can you also provides version with awk?

Comment: @holasz Is the initial `Somestring` a single word? And why do you need multiple ways of doing the same thing?

Comment: @Kusalanada I was just curious but got the awk verion from steeldriver. Thank you both. Since you were first, I considering your answer correct. Thanks .

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to do this in `awk`, then you need to anchor the expression - and you only need `sub` not `gsub` since it's a single replacement e.g.

```
awk '{sub(/\.[0-9][0-9]?[0-9]?$/,".x",$2)} 1' input
Somestring 1.2.3.x more charachters and strings
Somestring 1.2.3.x more charachters and strings
Somestring 1.2.3.x more charachters and strings
```

With *some* implementations you can use ERE `[0-9]{1,3}` for the digit repeat.

Answer (score 1):

```
awk '{sub(/.$/,"x",$2)}1' file

Somestring 1.2.3.x more charachters and strings
Somestring 1.2.3.x more charachters and strings
Somestring 1.2.3.x more charachters and strings
```